# Using Command Pattern for notepad design

Tags: design-patterns

I have an assignment of getting a notepad that limits the file size by 2 MB. We support all the normal notepad operations like open,save,undo,redo etc. My initial thought is to go by 'COMMAND Pattern" Is anything else can be used or suggested?

This is in c#

Comment: Why are you making a notepad with a file-size limit? Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: yes just trying to explore different design paterns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Command Pattern will certainly allow for easy-ish undo/redo functionality. Expanding the pattern out to full-MVC will allow for good organization of code, keeping the data (what users type) to be stored in the Model, handling of events (users typing, saving, etc) in the Controller (with strong Command Pattern implementation), and what users actually see handled in the View.

There are tons of resources available for learning about design patterns. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649643.aspx) Microsoft discusses MVC. [Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rmcochran/mvc_intro12122005162329pm/mvc_intro.aspx) is another introduction to MVC. [Here](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx) is a nice list of various other patterns. And [here](http://www.robotlegs.org/diagram/) is a great diagram explaining an MVC flow (not C#, but still applies).

Keep in mind that there is no 100% "this is the way MVC should be." As with most things code related, there is a goal (separation of Model and VIew), and you are crafting your project in the best way to try to reach it. There is no "one-size-fits-all."